# Powershell: Why does (gci c:\ddd).count on an Empty folder not return 0

Tags: powershell, count, null, get-childitem

Why does `(gci c:\ddd).count` on an Empty folder not return 0 but "nothing"

I just get an Error "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression." When my count-condition does not match.

What do i need to "get" the zero to prevent the exception?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the operator `@()` to make sure that the result is an array, including empty or containing a single item:

```
@(gci c:\ddd).count
```

Commands may return: 1) a collection; 2) a single object; 3) null. Your case is 3. Calling `.Count` on null (case 3) or on an object that does not have a property `Count` (case 2) gets nothing or may fail, for example, with strict mode enabled `Set-StrictMode -Version 2`.

`@(...)` is always an array and `Count` works.

Comment: Thank you! Sometimes it's simple ;-)